# Building library with gradle which is in a sibling directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm setting up an Android Studio project. This project has a uses some other libs which are included in the Git repository as submodules. So they have to be in the same root folder. (If this is wrong feel free to write an answer too this would fix me problem too.)

As far I understood gradle the dependencies the have to be in a subdirectory to use the `compile project ':subdir:subsubdir'` command.

I found something about the `include` command but I did not get it how to use this, this seems also to require files in any subdirectory. So I digged a little more and found the `flatDir` command in the scope of `repositories` but how can I use that?

If helpful or not here is my **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile project('../LibraryProjectName:Library')
    compile 'com.examlple.library:Library:1.0'
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs '../LibraryProjectName/Library'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, the library doesn't have to be located into a subdirectory, the dependencies management make a distinction between the logical path and the physical path. I'll now read the question and see if I can help ;)

Comment: Can you just add a simple description of the tree hierarchy (discriminating app and lib projects)?

Comment: Great, I'll provide an answer then! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I delt with the same tree hierarchy last week and made a simple sample to get the thing done.

Check out [this sample on github](https://github.com/nibua-r/OutOfTreeLibSample).

The key is the use of the `settings.gradle` files. This sample can be built both from the root directory and from the DummyProject directory.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble to use your cool example because I have in your `DummyLib` two more directories which itself contain projects (libary and sample). Now I'm not sure if I can just reference `../DummyLib/Libary` or if I have to use `DummyLib` and reference its subdirectory. +1 So far for your work.

Comment: Edit the DummyProject/settings.gradle equivalent to adapt the library path

Comment: Okay I got it now. I had to add one line in the settings.gradle in the root directory: `project(':DummyLib').projectDir = new File('DummyLib/Library')`. Now it seems to work fine :)

Comment: Yes but you cannot compile from DummyProject ;-)

Comment: Now I'm confused I found in some dir a running apk file but Android Studio is yelling that `MyProject\build\classes\debug\MyProject.apk` would not exists. If you like you can come in [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132), for avoiding more comments.

Comment: It worked, thanks! **include ':DummyLib'** This is what I needed in the project which depended on another project.

Comment: You can use `includeFlat`.  But it does not package the DummyLib into DummyProject.jar